# MySQL 5.6.25 socket error 10061

Tags: mysql, sockets, connection, database-connection

```
after update to 5.6.25
```

can not connect MySQL 5.6.25 , socket error 10061,
what should i do ?

Comment: look in the /etc/my.cnf There is the path of the socket, or mysql is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that, after you update to MySQL 5.6.25 all config file changed, you should to change connection limit from zero to another number